# Insert html elements to body using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have checkbox on the page. I am wrapping that checkbox in a div and insert label after checkbox using javascript. Now I want to add all these elements on the body but it does not work. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TVVyM/1/) is my code. I use

```
        document.body.innerHTML = wrapper;
```

in order to add those elements to body but it does not work. How can I make it work?

Comment: I don't understand, you're already using `appendChild()` on the wrapper. What makes you think appending to the `<body>` element should be done differently?

Comment: I want to show that checkbox. That wrapper is created using javascript which means it is not yet on the body. After insert two new elements inside wrapper now I want to show it to users to see. How can I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use   `document.body.innerHTML = wrapper;` please use `appendChild`:

```
wrapper.appendChild(c[i]);
wrapper.appendChild(label);
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TVVyM/3/).

Comment: Now when I check the checkbox it doesnt get checked. Why?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 2):

You only have to apply [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to the `<body>` element, just like you're already doing with the wrapper element:

```
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) is a string property that is supposed to be assigned raw HTML markup, not DOM elements.

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TVVyM/2/).